# Using .NET ConfigurationManager to read settings from a string instead of an app.config file

Tags: c#, configurationmanager, system.configuration

We are running multiple instances of our service (implemented as a .exe file) on different machines in our data center. However, we would like to store configuration parameters for this .exe file in a central location (as opposed to being in the .exe.config per machine).

To do this, we are planning to move the content of the .exe.config files to an attribute in a central repository (Active Directory or SQL) and make the .exe's running on all machines read from this repository.

I would like reuse all the existing classes used for reading/writing configuration information (using ConfigurationManager, ConfigurationProperty etc., basically using the entire .NET Configuration framework) - however, instead of loading it from the .exe.config file (which it does by default - I want it to load it from a string value of the XML blob that I will retrieve from that central repository.

I was trying to find ways to do it using the ConfigurationManager API but couldn't find anything that could load a Configuration Section from a string. Any pointers?

Comment: You need a different SettingsProvider.  There's a sample of one, should give enough hints on how to implement your own: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181001%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could write your own [ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx) that will then load the real config data from your central repository.

Alternatively, do you have some sort of centralized deployment system in place for installing software on your various servers? How does your service get deployed? Rather than adding complexity to your software you should look for existing tools that already solve your problem.

Comment: Thank Andrew for your comment. Re-using as much of the existing infrastructure is _exactly_ what we are aiming for. Our binaries get rolled out to our production datacenter via a centralized script. Currently, we deploy the .exe and .exe.config file on our datacenter machines. The problem is that there is no central way to control the configuration of the .exe and we don't want to re-deploy .exe.config files everywhere each time we want to change a configuration.

Additionally, the configuration code already leverages the .NET configuration section.

Answer (score 1):

Although I doubt this is what it was intended for, we've done this in our project using [ProtectedConfigurationProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.protectedconfigurationprovider.aspx). Basically, this class is supposed to allow you to encrypt your configuration file but we simply have the Decrypt method connect to our database and return the configuration information. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfc2t3az.aspx) for notes on implementing. This felt a little hacky, but we couldn't find any other way without completely rewriting all of the configuration parsing logic.