# ConfigurationManager without accessing a file

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

I'm writing C# that is running as a sandboxed plugin for a piece of 3rd party software.  As a result, I cannot load config by specifying a file for ConfigurationManager.

I can however, set up a file on the 3rd party server and retrieve the contents as a string.

Ideally I would like to feed my config-as-string into the ConfigurationManager and have a normal C# config system.  I've read the docs but couldn't see any to init config with a string (or buffer).  Is there a reasonable and easy way to do this?

My fallback plan is to make a simple format of [key]=[value]\n and loading that into a Dictionary.  I'd just like to avoid creating and maintaining a config system if possible.

Comment: This answer is loading from a database, but might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070088/c-sharp-initialize-appsettings-from-database

Comment: Saw this question in the *Related* area in the sidebar that may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779962/using-net-configurationmanager-to-read-settings-from-a-string-instead-of-an-app?rq=1

Comment: You can put your config into the 3rd party software and access it via the ConfigurationManager or load your configuration file manually. This is the two options I see

Comment: If you save your config-as-string into a temp file, you might be able to load it using these techniques: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425407/configurationmanager-appsettings-use-another-config-file

Comment: @Fidel Looks like you are right. And another similar answers at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738/using-configurationmanager-to-load-config-from-an-arbitrary-location)

Comment: @MichaelMurray - No database libraries in the sandbox

Comment: @Fidel - No file access of any kind, can't create a temp file (I probably _could_ break the sandbox, but that's a whole new can of worms)

Comment: @Sherman I more meant taking a similar approach.  Load an XML document into memory from a stream, update the ConfigurationManager like they did in that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you don't want to, but you can always roll your own.  Which is just what we did in a similar situation.  I posted some code I wrote for managing configuration that is thread-safe here:

[Where to store "factory defaults" configuration settings, so they may be updated programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841451/where-to-store-factory-defaults-configuration-settings-so-they-may-be-updated/31842425#31842425)

My post is at the bottom.

Comment: Sadly, I ended up having to roll my own.